# Is there a way to stop a RegEx before a character value and start another one after that character?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to remove numbers before a character such as `a-z` or `*`, `/`, `+`, `-`, and then remove any numbers following that character but before a different character. Here is what I have.

```
    s= s.replaceAll("(\\d+)", "");
    s= s.replace("*", r.toString());
```

Where `s` is the string that I need to read, and `r` is the result of the operation.

The `*` is arbitrary. It could be any char. previously mentioned

The problem with this is that it removes every number in the string.

If I were to iterate once with the input of:

```
    26 + 4 - 2
```

The program returns this:

```
    30 -
```

It deletes all three numbers and then replaces the "+" with 30.

I would like to change it to resemble this (with one iteration):

```
    26 + 4 - 2
```

The first RegEx would delete the first set of numbers

```
    + 4 - 2
```

The second would remove the numbers after the operator, but before the next operator

```
    + - 2
```

The next statement would replace the operator with the result of the expression

```
    30 - 2
```

I would like the same for problems with other functions such as sine, cosine, etc.

*Note: Sine is 'a'*

*"Sin pi" is the same as "a pi"*

After one iteration it should look like

```
    a pi + 2

    a + 2

    0 + 2
```

Here is a sample of the code.

This is the Multiply "case"

```
    case '*':
                    {
                        int m = n + 1;
                        while (m < result.length){
                            if (result[m] != '*' && result[m] != '/' && result[m] != '+' && result[m] != '-'){ //checks the item to see if it is numeric
                                char ch2 = result[m]; //makes the number a character
                                number3 += new String(new char[]{ch2}); //combines the character into a string. For example: '2' + '3' = "23".
                                ++m;}
                            else {
                                    break;
                                }}
                        resultNumber = (Double.parseDouble(number2) * Double.parseDouble(number3)); //"number2" holds the value of the numbers before the operator. Example: This number ----> "3" '*' "23"
                        equation = equation.replaceAll("(\\d+)", "");  //  <---- Line I pulled out earlier that I want to change.
                        equation = equation.replace("*", resultNumber.toString()); // <----- Line I pulled out earlier
                        result = equation.toCharArray();
                        number3 = ""; //erases any number held
                        number2 = ""; //erases any number held
                        ++n;
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: Very unclear. What exactly do you want to do with regex? You seem to be replacing expressions with their computed value. This isn't something that regex does (calculating results of arithmetic expressions).

Comment: What really is the question? All I can interpret is you need something that does math and matches patterns.

Comment: This kind of evaluation should generally be done by splitting the input string into words and then pushing them into a stack. Any particular reason you're using regular expressions?

Comment: You are trying to do the job of a tokenizer (also called lexer) / parser program with regexes. I've tried to do a calculator with only regexes and string substitution before, and while it ALMOST worked, it always had weird precedence corner cases I could never be 100% convinced I ironed out. So, I highly recommend you find a good parser library for Java, and write a parser for your calculator like I ended up doing in Python with its excellent PLY library. :)

Comment: I'm sorry that this is so unclear. I've always found trouble in wording questions like this one.  What I am trying to do is make a calculator with java.  The math part I have done, I just need to delete the numbers that are left behind.  I am relatively new to programming, and I don't fully understand tokenizers or stacks. I saw that RegEx can delete certain character types, and I was wondering if there was a way to stop it at a certain character so it would not delete numbers after that particular character.

Comment: It might be worth searching Google for postfix evaluations of expressions and the code for it. Its a far more simpler approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll first suggest two alternate approaches, then answer your question as it stands.

## Perhaps beter without regular expressions

I have many doubts about your application. A proper [tokenizer (lexer)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), together with a very simple [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Programming_languages) would likely do a better job and give clearer error messages than your code.

## Matching all operands

Even if you were to use regular expressions, it might make more sense to match both operands in a single pass. I.e. match `(\d+)\s*\*\s*(\d+)`  to match a multiplication of exactly two numbers. You could first search for a match, then extract the operands from the capturing groups, then compute the resulting value and finally glue together substrings including the result:

```
// Multiplication of unparenthesized integers
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s*\\*\\s*(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  int a = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
  int b = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
  s = s.substring(0, m.start(1)) + (a*b) + s.substring(m.end(2));
  m.reset(s);
}
```

## Answer to the question as it was phrased in the title

Regarding the exact formulation of your question:

> Is there a way to stop a RegEx before a character value and start another one after that character?

If you want a regex to not match after a given character in the input, you can achieve that by a negative look-behind assertion. Likewise, to only match after a given character, you can use a positive look-behind assertion.

So a regex starting in `(?<!\*.*)` would only match up to the first occurrence of `'*'`, whereas a regex starting in `(?<=\*.*)` would only match after the first occurrence of that character. Both would have to be compiled using `DOTALL`, or in a more complicated form like `(?<!\*(?:\n|.*)*)`.

But ensuring that these matches correspond to the math you have in mind would likely be very tricky.

Comment: I will keep the tokenizer method in mind, but the other method also solved the problem I was having and I think I understand it more. Thank you!